# Functional component data table not rerendering when add/remove columns which is set/stored in state in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am building a datatable and have added a checkbox dropdown for adding/removing columns in the table. Everything works fine *except* it is not rerendering the table until I click on one of the header titles.

At the top of the function component, I am setting the state as follows:

```
  const [formColumns, setDisplayFields] = useState(formFields);
```

formFields is retrieved from a file and is formatted as below. It's an array of JSON column objects that looks like this:

```
    [id: {
      name: 'id',
      label: 'Patient Id',
      displayColumn: false,
      displayOrder: 1,
    },
    firstName: {
      name: 'firstName',
      label: 'First Name*',
      requiredErrorMsg: 'First name is required',
      displayColumn: true,
      displayOrder: 2,
    },
    middleName: {
      name: 'middleName',
      label: 'Middle Name',
      displayColumn: false,
      displayOrder: 0,
    },
    lastName: {
      name: 'lastName',
      label: 'Last Name*',
      requiredErrorMsg: 'Last name is required',
      displayColumn: true,
      displayOrder: 0,
    },
    suffix: {
      name: 'suffix',
      label: 'Suffix',
      displayColumn: false,
      displayOrder: 0,
    },
    dob: {
      name: 'dob',
      label: 'Date of Birth*',
      requiredErrorMsg: 'Birth date is required',
      invalidErrorMsg: 'This is not a valid date',
      displayColumn: true,
      displayOrder: 3,
    },
    organization: {
      name: 'organization',
      label: 'Organization',
      displayColumn: false,
      displayOrder: 4,
    },
  ]
```

There are actually more columns, but this should suffice for describing what I'm doing.  The 'displayColumn' element is changed in an onChange event in the same component that displays the table (passes it as a prop into checkbox menu).  Here's the onchange:

```
  /**
   * handleCheckboxSelect
   * @param {string} colname
   */
  var handleCheckboxSelect = (colname) =>
  {
    //return the index of the column checked/unchecked
    var icol = getColumnIndex(formColumns, colname);
    console.log('FOUND COLINDEX = ' + icol + '.');
    if (icol > -1) {
      //toggle the display parameter
      formColumns[icol].displayColumn = (formColumns[icol].displayColumn === false);
      //store the updated column in the column list
      setDisplayFields(formColumns);
    }
    else {
      console.log('checkbox colname = ' + colname);
    }
  }
```

As you can see, I am using state as required, and any time state changes, it should force a re-render.  However, it's not.  Is it because I am using an array of objects?  If I pass a single column back and stroe that in state, would that fix the issue?  I'm stumped.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting same `formColumns` reference on `setDisplayFields` which will not trigger re-render of the component. Try to copy `formColumns` to a new array and make changes on that array.

Try this -

```
var handleCheckboxSelect = (colname) =>
  {
    //create new array from existing one
    let newColumns = [...formColumns];

    var icol = getColumnIndex(newColumns, colname);
    console.log('FOUND COLINDEX = ' + icol + '.');
    if (icol > -1) {
      //toggle the display parameter
      newColumns[icol].displayColumn = (newColumns[icol].displayColumn === false);
      //store the updated column in the column list
      setDisplayFields(newColumns);
    }
    else {
      console.log('checkbox colname = ' + colname);
    }
  }
```

Comment: So, I can't just replace an object in an array of objects and expect react to re-render?  It only does a shallow compare of an object?  Yikes.  if true, that's gonna force me to redesign.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks!  Unfortunately, realized too late that I should be using objects in a different way in react.